# How exactly do you pass arrays through the parameters of a function?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have a project for my class that basically reads 3 students info (each student has 3 courses, and 5 tests, along with info like their name, ssn, phone number, etc.) from an input file, stores the input in arrays, then outputs the information into an output file. The project must be split into 6 functions, not including the main function.

I can successfully read and store the information, but when i go to the "validateData" function, my array is not being passed through to the function, so it will not be able to validate it. This error is also happening throughout the other functions as well. I believe it is probably an error with the prototypes of the functions, as that is what i am mostly confused about it.

i have tried changing the prototype parameters to (string[],int[],double[]) because i have 3 different arrays, one for the strings, one for the ints, and one for the doubles. But this has not worked. I also tried the same thing except without these "[]", still was not working, i believe the error said that the compiler was unable to change a double* into a double, or vice versa.

```
//Declaring global constants
const int STUDENTS = 3;
const int NONNUMERIC_INFO = 9;
const int NUMERIC_INFO = 2;
const int COURSES = 3;
const int TESTS_and_CNG = 6;
```

```
//Above main function, Function prototype
void validateData(string [], int [], double []);
```

```
//Inside main function, Function call
    validateData();
```

```
//Declaring Arrays (inside of a different function called inputData)
string nonNumeric1[STUDENTS][NONNUMERIC_INFO];
int numeric1[STUDENTS][NUMERIC_INFO];
double numeric2[STUDENTS][COURSES][TESTS_and_CNG];
```

```
//Under main function, Function definition
void validateData(string, int, double)
{
 //A bunch of if statements that i will soon turn into for loops, but will save you guys the trouble of reading them all, as its not important to the question.
}
```

I am expecting the arrays to be passed through into the function, however it is not doing so and giving me an error saying "error: too few arguments to function 'void validateData(std::__cxx11::string*, int*, double*)'" I am unaware of what the error message is trying to say.

Comment: You're literally not passing anything to `validateData`, despite saying that you will pass a `string[]` etc. How would you expect the program to know what you want to pass? What if you had a bunch of arrays, how would you expect it to know which ones to pass. You have to specify what you wanna pass to the function. Also your definition doesn't match your declaration

Comment: We have just learned about arrays and functions, and my prof isn't a very good one. So are you saying my definition should also include the brackets as well? I could have swore that he said in class that you dont need the brackets in the definition if you put them in the declaration. Also, what information should i have in the brackets? and what should be in the parameters of the function call? Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good job with the prototype function but your function title lines don't match.

**Your Prototype**:

```cpp
//Above main function, Function prototype
void validateData(string [], int [], double []);
```

**Your Function**:

```cpp
void validateData(string, int, double)
```

Secondly, although your prototype may no need variable names, your function title line certainly does.

`void validateData(string, int, double)` your function here only has variable types. I'd check out a tutorial like [declaring functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_functions.htm) if you aren't fully familiar with declaring functions.

Finally, once you've matched up your prototype function title line and your actual function title line and gave your actual function parameters variable names, you'll need to fix your function call.

You call your function like so: `validateData();` This again, doesn't match your function title line. Your function title line says that `validateData` takes a `string array`, `int` and a `double`. Your function call passes nothing `()`. If you want your `array`, `int` and `double` to appear in the function you need to pass them in the function call. `validateData(some_array, some_int, some_double)`.

Don't forget to replace `some_array`, `some_int` ... etc with actual variables with their respective types.

Edit:

If you're looking to call the `validateData` method inside `inputData` you'd have to do something like:

```
void inputeData(....) {

 validateData(some_array, some_int, some_double);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! This is actually starting to make sense to me now. When i call the function with the proper parameters, the program will still not work, because the arrays were declared in my inputData function. Is there a way for me to pass the arrays from this inputData function, into other functions, like the validateData function or will I have to declare the functions globally? In class, the professor specifically said to only declare global constants, so i took that as him saying not to globally declare the arrays, not sure if that is what he meant though.

Comment: If you're in the `inputData` function, you can call (inside the `inputData` func.) the `validateData` function

Comment: would that look like `validateData(inputData(string Array[], int Array2[], double Array3[]))`? or do i not need the arrays inside the parameters?